# Report of groups and number of members

Tags: groups, reports

I would like to have a report that lists:

- the name of each group
- the description of each group
- the number of members in each group

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is maybe a silly answer but works:

1. Visit this url, replacing example.com with your site. http://example.com/civicrm/ajax/grouplist?snippet=4&draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=title&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=count&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=created_by&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=description&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=group_type&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=visibility&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=links&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=0&length=25&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&title=&created_by=&group_type=&visibility=&status=1&component_mode=1&showOrgInfo=&parentsOnly=1&_=1585333964030
2. That gives you effectively the same output as the table you see when you go to Contacts - Manage Groups.
3. In chrome copy the output to the clipboard. In firefox you need to click the raw data tab first, then copy to the clipboard.
4. Go to https://www.convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm
5. Paste in the box.
6. Scroll a little bit down and you'll see a Download Result button. That will give you a .csv file which opens in excel.

Unfortunately you can't just copy and paste the table at Manage Groups directly into excel because where it appears on the screen isn't where it actually is in the DOM, so when you try to select the browser is confused and you get a whole bunch of other stuff. Otherwise that would be a simpler answer, although it works in Chrome, but not Firefox.

Comment: Wow, I am impressed. It worked exactly as you described.   I would have never guessed. Thank you so much.
I did also discover another method.  I exported the table civicrm_group as a *,csv file and imported in to a spreadsheet and had the data too. 
I like your method, because it can be done by a non-techie. Thanks again.

Comment: What an unexpected answer! How did you create the URL for this request?

Comment: @WilliamMortada In firefox for example you can see it on the network tab in developer tools when you visit Contacts - Manage groups.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to see that information, rather than it being in a report, then go to `Contacts > Manage Groups`  Click the button `Update Smart Group Counts` to refresh the count data.